# Is my output correct regarding the example data I've been provided for this database?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've created a database in SQL with insert statements for some data. What I can't understand is, my registration table output looks much different than the example data I've been given for the registration table. My table contains corresponding ID's while the example data has those outputs in text. Will I have to create joins afterwards? I thought It could display the ID's in text while creating the database. Here is the example data I'm supposed to follow, and what my output looks like in my database.

[image: Example Data Registration]
[image: My sql registration output]

Comment: Which is it -- sql-server or mysql?  Is ssms creating the `INSERTs`; if so, will it also create the `JOINs`?